# VS Code looking for image in wrong path

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have a folder for a project, in that folder i have another folder that holds images. when i open the project folder in vs code and i click on each image i can see them just fine, but as soon as i link it to use as a background image VS Code looks in the wrong path for it. I've already cleared the cache but it didn't help.

for example, the images are in:
project/assets/img/img1.jpg

when i link it as a background image and ctrl+click:
project/assets/css/assets/img/img1.jpg

Comment: use a relative path in your CSS `url()`